# Ajax login fails to authenticate and set cookies the first time, but works every time afterwards

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I am using a javascript login form, using Ajax to call the authorisation function, and upon success, redirecting to the 'dashboard' section of the website. Upon opening the website for the first time and logging in, the script successfully redirects to the dashboard BUT without authorisation being successful. That is, the cookies are not set. So nothing happens.

But if I refresh back to index.php (cookies not set at this point here either) and login a second time, the login is successful as the cookies are set. If I then logout, and log back in, it works perfectly. The only time that I have had an issue is the very first time that the website is opened in a browser. Can anyone help me figure out why?

The logic, as I see it, is as follows:

1. Javascript in header.php uses Ajax to send $_POSTed values to ajax.php.
2. Ajax.php takes the $_POSTed variables, includes the user class, and calls the authorisation function.
3. Upon success, the authorisation function sets cookies (userID, email etc) and returns TRUE.
4. Ajax.php takes the true, returns yes.
5. Javascript in the header function takes the response, redirects the page to the dashboard.

I have a feeling it's to do with the fact that the page must be refreshed to set cookies, but I can find no consistent reason as to why the code works perfectly all but the very first time.

Code:

header.php

```
function loginAjax() {
    var email = document.getElementById("login").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
    // AJAX code to submit form.
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "classes/ajax.php",
    data: {"Email": email, "Password": password},
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
        if(response == "yes") {
    window.location.href="http://www.draftreview.com.au/index.php?content=dashboard";
    } else {
    $("#loginerror").html("<p style=\"color:red;font-size:14px;margin:12px 0px -10px 0px;\">Username or Password Error</p>");
    }},
    error: function(data)
    {
       console.log(arguments);
    }
    });
    return false;
    }
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
include_once('user.php');
$user = new User;
$email = $_POST['Email'];
$password = $_POST['Password'];

if($user->userAuthorised($email, $password)) {
 echo "yes";
}

?>
```

user.php

```
function userAuthorised($email, $password) {

        //Hash the password entered by the user.
        $md5Password = md5($password);

        //Prepare select statement of the ID, password, accessLevel.
        $tuser_SQLselect = "SELECT ID, password FROM tuser WHERE email = '".$email."'";

        //Run query and store the values in an associative array.
        $tuser_SQLselect_Query = mysqli_query($this->connect(), $tuser_SQLselect); 

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($tuser_SQLselect_Query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $userID = $row['ID'];
            $passwordRetrieved = $row['password'];
        }

        /*
        * Checks whether the password entered is equal to the password stored in
        * the tuser database. Sets cookies.
        */
        if (!empty($passwordRetrieved) AND ($md5Password == $passwordRetrieved)) {

                setcookie("userID", $userID, 0, "/");   
                setcookie("loginAuthorised", "loginAuthorised", 0, "/");
                setcookie("email", $email, 0, "/");
```

...

The function continues to other irrelevant stuff and returns true. The syntax is all good.

[EDIT] For testing, if you'd like:

website: draftreview.com.au
email: testingso@test.com
password: password1

Comment: i don't see you setting the cookie after the ajax is complete

Comment: Any working site we can see? Hard to find anything in the code posted here.

Comment: email: testingso@test.com
password: password1
website: draftreview.com.au
@vbrmnd